# Specify boolean variable using environment variables in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Given the following program:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "Prefix_");
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

and a configuration usually defined in `appsettings.json` as:

```
{
    "SomeSection": {
        "SomeOption": true
    }
}
```

is there a way to override it as environment variable (using [the method specified in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#environment-variables-configuration-provider))?

---

I've tried with (I'm on macOS, but the same problem also happens in Linux and Docker Compose):

```
export Prefix_SomeSection__SomeOption=true
```

but it's parsed as a string and it can't convert it to a boolean. The same method **works with every other non boolean option**, which seems to imply that there's some undocumented way to define a variable as a boolean.

Comment: Tried `0` and `1` yet?

Comment: Where's the code that attempts to consume the value?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think so but I'm not sure. I can't try it at the moment. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: @KirkLarkin `services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SomeSection"));` Where `AppConfig` defines `SomeOption` to be a boolean.

Comment: What do you mean can't convert it to boolean? I made a test with docker compose with `environment:
      - Prefix_SomeSection__SomeOption=true` and `bool value = _appConfig.SomeOption;`, it works correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was setting the environment variables with `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  server:
    environment:
      Prefix_SomeSection__SomeOption: true
```

the error that I got was related to `docker-compose.yml`, not .NET Core, and it was:

> contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

The solution is to just wrap that `true` into a string like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  server:
    environment:
      Prefix_SomeSection__SomeOption: "true"
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to answer your own question when you found the solution.

Comment: How can you set it to false?